# How can I add a simple shape-indicator to the end of the progress line on a ProgressBar?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Lately I've had to re-style my WPF application based off of a style guide given to me by a designer.  One of my new requirements is to change the look of the `ProgressBar`.

Most of the changes are rather simple, however what I'm having a difficult time figuring out is how can I add a simple shape to the end of the progress line.
I'm *not* trying to draw a shape at the far-right edge of the progress bar.  Instead, If the progress meter is at 50%, I'd like to draw a Circle at the 50% point, and so on.  Below is a sample image of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Please note, I've done something similar for the `Slider` control.  However, it appears to be a much different beast.  Thanks for the guidance.

[image: Updated ProgressBar]

Comment: I think you need a converter :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works for me

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#235b92" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#235b92" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e8f0f7" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                  Margin="10,5">
                            <Border x:Name="PART_Track"
                                    BorderThickness="2"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                            <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                                <Ellipse Fill="#06e5ed" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="-10,-5"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

That code yields the following result for me:
[image: Progress result]

Whereas the red dotted area is just the highlighted PART_Indicator control

Comment: Not quite.  I tried this.  The PART_Indicator appears to be the container that can house counts or "Percent Complete" stats.  I stays at the center of the ProgressBar.  If this isn't the case, it's not how it behaved for me when I tried code very-similar to this.

Comment: For me that code gives exactly the result you described in your post.
The PART_Indicator scales exactly to the current progress and as i add the ellipse inside the Indicator control on the right border with negative margin it is exactly centered at the end of the progress, so with 50% right in the center of the control

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Let me see what I can make happen on my end. I had to mess around a bit with margins to get this to work right, so I could have set a value with unexpected results that kept it centered.

Comment: I've been messing around with this today.  This does work, but the one problem is that it kills the animation for the `IsIndeterminate` state.

Comment: Thats right, this one is only for Determinate style, but you could just use VisualStateManager for the indeterminate ProgressBar. Maybe this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/progressbar-styles-and-templates